# Since Layer.com does not have a web SDK yet, what can I use to integrate it myself for a web-mobile chat app?

Tags: android, mobile, web-applications, parse-platform, layer

[Layer](http://layer.com) looks awesome for mobile development, however, in case we need to build a web to mobile chat, the web SDK is not yet available. Can we integrate it with parse to do so? Or maybe some other solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Web SDK is currently in Early Access so it's available to be used.  You could potentially use the combination of the Platform API and Parse cloud code to do a partial chat from web to mobile in the meantime, but it depends on your use case.

Comment: FYI, the Client API is now available publicly. You can find out more details here: http://blog.layer.com/introducing-layer-client-api/

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Layer but I think(hope) you can send http request (REST api) to parse and trigger the cloud function. So  the cloud function can send your message to your mobile client as a push notification. After that, the only thing that you have to do is handling the push notification cases such that when the app is opened, when the app is closed or when the app is on chat screen. Hope this helps.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Another good alternative is Hyphenate. Similar to Layer, but Hyphenate supports both Mobile and Web SDK with rich features and very reliable services.

Parse is good, but shutting down soon, an good alternative is Firebase by Google.

https://hyphenate.io/

https://github.com/HyphenateInc/Hyphenate-SDK-Web